# interp1d type="linear" gives not precise result

Tags: python, scipy, scaling, interpolation

I noticed that interp1d gives possibly wrong result.
At least the results are different than the result of analogical process in Gimp and Photoshop. Where the results of Gimp and Photoshop are almost identical.
Perhaps it is related to some round-offs in the scipy code.

Would you know how to eliminate the differences? I have reasons to suspect that the results from the graphic software are closer to perfection.

*In all the below cases i use only 1 row of pixels and perform horizontal scaling. For the clarity the images consist more rows*

Here is the very fancy, original image (#000000 pixels separated evenly on #0000FF background) :

**unscaled image**

[image: original image]

Below are the  scipy scaling results along with the results from gimp and Photoshop. I tried many different scaling options in the above mentioned software, as well as in python interpolation. Actually in this quite radical case, different types of scaling (cubic,linear) give the same result in scipy.

*(You may need to zoom in the image in the browser. I did not want to perform additional scaling to not affect original results)*

**gimp/scipy type="linear"**

[image: gimp-scipy comparison]

**scipy linear/photoshop/scipy cubic**
[image: photoshop-scipy comparison]

**profiles**
*(i cropped out the non-meaningful long breaks of plain blue color)*

[image: profile plot 1]
[image: profile plot 2]

On profile plots the problem is less visible - especially in case of gimp-scipy. On bitmaps the difference is quite obvious. The middle lines overlap perfectly - but the further we move to the sides the more we can see difference in distances. How to obtain more proper, "gimp-like" result?
The problem for me is not as much the values of the pixels but the distances between the dark pixels. I am happy with linear interpolation and do not need cubic, but I included it in the question for science (and comparison).

**My code used for interpolation**

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import pygame

def splineDecodeColors2(oldchain,newchain):
   L0,L1 = len(oldchain[0]),len(newchain[0])
   chain0 = np.array(oldchain)
   x0 = np.linspace(0, L0-1, L0)
   chain1 = np.array(newchain)


   for color in xrange(3):
     try:
        f = interp1d(x0, chain0[color], kind= 'linear')
        x  = np.linspace(0, L0-1, L1)
        chain1[color] = f(x).round()
     except ValueError, error:
        print error # possibly len(chain)==1
        chain1[color]=chain0[color]


   return chain1.T



def saveToPNG(img,name):
    name=str(name)
    img = np.array([img,img,img])
    img  = np.rot90(img,3)
    pygame.image.save(pygame.surfarray.make_surface(img),name+".png")



def main():
    a = np.array([[ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 0.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.], [ 0., 0., 255.]]).T

    b= np.zeros([3,592])
    c = splineDecodeColors2(a,b)
    saveToPNG(c,"interlpolated")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you give directions on how to reproduce your results?

Comment: As requested, I updated the code to reproduce the results (just copy+paste and run)

Comment: Your code considers the leftmost and rightmost pixels only half-pixel wide, as you don't put your data points at the centers of the pixels. interp1d works correctly, but you are asking it to do something else than what you are trying to do.

Comment: @pv. Thanks! What you suggest makes sense, but I am not sure how to center data at pixels. It is "np.linspace" lines that need to be changed? But then - how? i tried to increase the size of the input array by appending extra entries but it does not give proper results either. Also if you could put your answer as as separate post i could mark it as an anwser.